# Performing lookup with map

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class MapLookup {

    public void searchMap(){

        School x = new School("Rybeka");

        Map<School,School.Student> check = new HashMap<School,School.Student>();

        check.put(x,School.createNewStudent("Joy"));
        check.put(x,School.createNewStudent("Bob"));
        check.put(x,School.createNewStudent("Kate"));

        System.out.println(check.containsValue("Bob"));
    }
}
```

When i try perform lookups it return a false expression

Comment: You are checking if a `Map` of `Student`'s containts a `String`

Comment: “Bob” is a string and the map hold students as values.

Comment: “Bob” is a string and the map hold students as values.

Comment: You are using the same key for all 3 put statements, this will return true `System.out.println(check.containsValue("Kate"));` check basics of Map in java.

Comment: @dkb I don't think that it true. Try typing-in the code to see if it behaves the way you expect.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz check https://stackoverflow.com/a/53970544/2987755, mybad it should be `System.out.println(check.containsValue(School.createNewStudent("Kate")));`, point was it should be "Kate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would return `true` for you is

```
System.out.println(check.containsValue(School.createNewStudent("Kate")));
```

since that is the object you've put as `value` in the map at last and shall override other values mapped to the same key.

*Note*: This is assuming that `School.createNewStudent("Kate")` will return an object of a class that overrides `Object.equals` to use that "Kate" parameter.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff Yes, you're right. Coincidentally, I made the edit while you were making the comment. We were both thinking on the same lines. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Thanks so much, you are right i was using string  object instead of students.